# How can I detect scrolling for update before end dragging event in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gestures

I want to add update gesture in some views in my iOS application
Usually this gesture is scroll above top and hold for some small time

I could make just gesture handler that works if user did hold scrolled view more than 1 second:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == _tableView) {
        _scrollViewDragStarted = [NSDate date];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    if (scrollView == _tableView) {
        if (velocity.y < 0 && targetContentOffset->y < 0) {
            NSTimeInterval hold = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:_scrollViewDragStarted];
            if (hold > 1) {
                // refreshing method calls here
            }
        }
        _scrollViewDragStarted = nil;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly but hint about holding is needed when user scrolled view above top

How can I detect such scrolling?
`scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` event has no scroll parameters as `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`

Or maybe exist another way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)`.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll

Note that you can use `UIScrollView.contentOffset.y < 0` to check whether it has scrolled above the top.

Comment: specifically, detect that `contentOffset.y < 0`

Answer (score 0):

> 1) 
>   You can use refreshcontrol and customize it the way you want. Would recommend using this as its core api and gives you fun animations as well. plus this is generic and used everywhere so user would already know how to use compare to your scroll and hold-for-a-second gesture.
>
> -(void)viewDidLoad {
>   ...
>      UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
>      [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
>      [self.myTableView addSubview:refreshControl];
>   ...
>   }
>
> -(void)handleRefresh:(id)sender {
>       // do your refresh here... }

Answer (score 0):

you can use KVO for `contentffset` parameter

here is one of my Github repository

[UIScrollView-XYPlusingRefresh](https://github.com/levinXiao/UIScrollView-XYPlusingRefresh)

contact me if you want xiaoyulevin@gmail.com